# Attempt to de-reference a null object when calling class method from Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I am trying to write a test method that calls a method in my class to get some configuration data.  The method in my class returns a Map.   From my test method, when I call the method in my class, **I get an error which happens when I call `APIService.getSystemSettings();`**

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

My code is below:

```
  private class APIServiceTest {

    @isTest static void APITest() {
      Map<String,String> envSettings = new Map<String,String>();
      envSettings = APIService.getSystemSettings();
    }

 }
```

Here is the class which contains the method I am calling:

```
public class APIService {

  static API_Settings__c apiSettings = API_Settings__c.getValues('apisettings')        
  static Map<String,String> envSettings = new Map<String,String>();

  public static Map<String,String> getSystemSettings() {
   envSettings.put('customerURL', apiSettings.customer_url__c);
  }

}
```

Most of my methods in APIService are methods annotateded with @Future(Callout=true) so that is why most of the variables are declared as static methods.

I am trying to determine why I am getting this error and what is needed to fix it.

Comment: is it hierarchical custom setting or list custom setting?

Comment: It is list custom setting @PranayJaiswal

Comment: You have to insert the custom settings in testContext in testSetup. See David's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In unit test context, Custom Settings are treated as data (*not* metadata), and hence are not visible due to [test isolation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm).

Your unit test's setup, whether in your `@isTest` or an `@testSetup` method, must construct and insert any Custom Settings records you wish to have available to your test code.

You get a `NullPointerException` because there is no visible `API_Settings__c` instance called `apisettings`; it's `null`.